# regEx wp core file

Tags: tinymce, regex

I have an issue with the way WordPress handles creating a page anchor.  The page anchor button is already defined in the WordPress TinyMCE code.. and can be added using either the [Ultimate Tinymce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-tinymce/) or the [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) plugin.

When clicking the page anchor button, a popup opens asking the name of anchor to be defined.

If entering all letters `(myAnchor)`, everything works as expected.

If entering letters and numbers, beginning with a letter `(myAnchor123)`, it works as expected.

But when entering an anchor beginning with a number `(123myAnchor)`... an error is thrown.

Here is the code from the WordPress file `wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/js/anchor.js`:

```
if (!name || !/^[a-z][a-z0-9\-\_:\.]*$/i.test(name)) {
    tinyMCEPopup.alert('advanced_dlg.anchor_invalid');
    return;
}
```

I am terrible with the `regEx` function.  What I would like to do, is to keep the current functionality, but also add the ability to add anchors which begin with a number.

Any suggestions on how the new `regEx` should appear?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question.
Simply adding a `0-9` into the code above remedied the situation.

Here is the final code:

```
if (!name || !/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-\_:\.]*$/i.test(name)) {
    tinyMCEPopup.alert('advanced_dlg.anchor_invalid');
    return;
}
```